# How to add padding to an element that is auto wrapping inside TD

Tags: jquery, css, padding, word-wrap

I am trying to find a way to add some sort of padding/margin to an element that is auto wrapping due to a (needed) max-width of 300px. The element is inside a TD which I cannot change unfortunately. This is part of menu that pulls content from a database for many different member sites. It's a template based system.

The area that is affected is the location list. In the following example site the location titled: "Example Salon & Spa - At A Really Long Location" is the problem area. Its on the right side under Choose a Location:

[This is What The Menu Looks Like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIgsq.png)

http://www.mysalonorspaname.com/services.asp

I have tried using pseudo-class elements for the second line but since there's no line break in the actual code that didn't work. I also tried some other 'hacks' I found such as the box-shadow property but cant seem to get the result I want. I would like to have about 10px padding on the right of the 'first line' and 10px padding to the left of the 'second line'. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated - css or jquery solutions preferred! Thanks so much!

### Heres The Code Im working with:

```
<div id="mainContent">
<div id="newAside">
<div class="asideLocationList">
<table cellpadding='3' cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
<tr>
<td class='LocListHeader'>Choose a Location</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='LocListAltRow1'>
<a class='linkloc' href='?LID=12197'>Example Salon & Spa</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='LocListAltRow2'>
<a class='linkloc' href='?LID=13567'>Example Salon & Spa - At A Really Long Location</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
html, body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, address, time, span, em, strong, img, ol, ul, li, figure, canvas, video, th, td, tr, iframe {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
vertical-align:baseline;
font: inherit;
}

body 
{
top:0;
width: 100%;
font-family: "rucksack-1","rucksack-2",sans-serif;
line-height: 1.5;
color: #bebebe;
font-weight:normal;
font-style:normal;  
min-width:1080px

}
td, tr, table
{
color: #bebebe;   
}
#mainbox
{
width:100%;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
display:inline-block;
margin:0;


}

#mainContent

{
width:95%;
max-width:100%;
margin:30px auto;
vertical-align: baseline;

}
#newAside {
display:list-item;
float:right;
margin:0 20px 30px 0;
padding: 10px;
vertical-align: baseline;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px  #3a3a3a;  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 4.0.2 - 4.2, Android 2.3+ */
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 10px 0px #3a3a3a;  /* Firefox 3.5 - 3.6 */
box-shadow:         0px 0px 10px 0px #3a3a3a;  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Firefox 4+, Chrome 6+, iOS 5 */
}
.servCatList, .asideLocationList ul, .asideLocationList
{
display:block;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom:15px;
list-style: none;
max-width:300px;

}
.servCatList a, .asideLocationList a
{

background-color:rgba(0,0,0, 0.6); 
line-height:2.5em;
border:1px solid #424242;
padding:8px;
}
.servCatList a:hover, .asideLocationList a:hover
{

background-color: #424242;
color:#858470;
padding:8px;
margin-top:5px;
margin-bottom:5px;
}

.LocListAltRow2, .LocListAltRow1
{
font-size:1em;
display:block;
font-weight:normal;
border: none;
background-color:transparent; 
line-height:2.5em;
border:none;

}
```

Comment: please provide the code you are working with

Comment: Please don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: well, its a lot of code - ill put what I can here but if you inspect element on the actual page I posted above you can see everything...

Comment: thanks for the advice, I have posted the html and css that applies to this problem in the question above

Answer (score 0):

why you don't use the css definition to the TD Element? then you will have the padding without problem and i think when it's a line break, it should anyway not appear as 2 different buttons

Comment: The element is a link inside the TD element, when I add padding to the TD it moves the entire block to but the problem persists... what I want is to have the link have padding at the end of what appears to be the first line and the beginning of the second line (even though there are no actual line breaks)

Answer (score 0):

Add to your linkclass linkloc the definition inline-block:

```
.linkloc {
  display: inline-block;
}
```